# How to find travel time using a velocity matrix $vel[x][t]$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, computational-physics, integration, calculus

I have a velocity matrix which depends on both position $x$ and time $t$ i.e. $vel[x][t]$. How can I calculate the travel time between two points $x1$ and $x2$? How do I implement $$t = \int_{x1}^{x2} \frac{dx}{vel[x][t]}~?$$ when I don't have a functional form of velocity field? Is there any integration method or any other numerical method to tackle this problem?

Comment: If you have the velocity matrix you can supposedly use it to calculate that integral numerically no?

Comment: can you show me?

Comment: Try any of these [numerical integration methods](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/MATH_2200%3A_Calculus_for_Scientists_II/2%3A_Techniques_of_Integration/2.5%3A_Numerical_Integration_-_Midpoint%2C_Trapezoid%2C_Simpson's_rule)